# getting value from describe functions

Tags: python, pandas

I have this stock data and I want to grab the 25% percentile value. How do I do that?

```
swing=((1-(stock['Low']/stock['High']))*100).fillna(0)

swing.describe()
swing=((1-(stock['Low']/stock['High']))*100).fillna(0)
​
swing.describe()
count    206.000000
mean       3.328698
std        1.401410
min        1.135063
25%        2.299500
50%        3.005152
75%        3.945126
max       10.269701
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Try `swing.describe()["25%"]`?

Comment: can you put it as an answer so I can check it as answer? thank you